# .NET: which element is defining the feed location?

Tags: c#, .net, url

I have a .NET tool designed to my specifications, but the developer has gone AWOL and I need help.

When I run the tool, I can see that the data feed is coming from two different locations (names changed to protect client!):

http://www.leg.co.uk
https://editorial.leg.co.uk

I'm informed that the second is the more reliable. Unfortunately, the first URL supplies the majority of my feeds, which has been suffering from a page count failure, and so I'd like to try to change all feeds to the latter.

Can anyone help me identify which element of the tool this URL direction is coming from? I've searched the xml and dll files (using .NET reflector) but so far, I've not found "https://editorial.leg.co.uk" in any of these files, despite the evidence that at least some of the feed comes from there. I can therefore infer that I haven't found the correct element which is defining the location from where the feed ... is fed!

Composition of the tool.
.bat files point to ".\publish\XXTablesConsole.exe --settingsfile=config/settingsSIBV.xml"
"publish" folder contains

- "config" with a separate .xml for each publication
- various 2 letter named folders (cs/de/es) each with "FSharp.Core.resources.dll"
- 252 .dll files
- 2 .json files
- 1 .pdb file
- 2 exe files: "tables console" and "create dump".

As a total amateur, I've tried editing the .xml files within the config folder.

I thought this row with the mention of "baseURL" would be a good candidate:

This didn't work, and on reflection, this cannot be the source, since there's no direction toward editorial.leg .

I've tried opening and searching dll files.
I have not tried opening the exe file.

(I'm trying also to get the developer/client to resolve the initial page count failure but have been asking for help since November!)

Thanks in advance for your advice.